# CUDA combined with OpenMP

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

I saw a few threads on this but they don't seem to relate to the problem I'm having.

I have my CUDA code which works, but I want to parallelize the for loops that are running asynchronously with the kernel code (and after the kernel has finished as well).

I seem to be having a linking problem though... the errors are as such.

> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'omp_get_num_threads'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'omp_get_thread_num'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'GOMP_barrier'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'GOMP_single_start'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'GOMP_critical_start'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'GOMP_critical_end'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   '__gxx_personality_v0'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'GOMP_parallel_start'
>
> .../lib/liblalinference.so: error: undefined reference to
>   'GOMP_parallel_end'

First I'd like to point out that I have had opemMP work before but in a separate section where I compiled the C code with

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2 *many flags here* -fopenmp
```

Everything else there is extraneous information, the important part is that I just had to add the -fopenmp to the flag line in the makefile.

However, since CUDA is all complex and such with using nvcc which sort of uses a c++ compiler as its backbone (right?), I seem to be at a loss.  When I add -fopenmp to

```
CPPFLAGS =  ... *many cuda flags* -fopenmp
```

I get the stated errors above.

I've even tried

```
CPPFLAGS =  ... *many cuda flags* -fopenmp -lgomp
```

It is also noted that when I configure my project the GCC flags are disabled when CUDA is enabled.

Where am I going wrong?  Do I need to put the flag(s) elsewhere? Do I need to give up?

Comment: How are you passing the `-fopenmp` flag to nvcc? You have to use `-Xcompiler` in front. Also, have you included `omp.h`?

Comment: Yes I have #include <omp.h>.  Also, I didn't create the makefile, and it's mostly automake so I don't know exactly how it's being passed.  However, I assume that it is being passed correctly or I would be getting other errors.  I will try to use -Xcompiler in front, however I thought -xcompiler=-fopenmp ?

Comment: Sorry, I just found out. nvcc is passed arguments by such...


 $(nvcc_verbose)${NVCC} -arch=sm_20 --cuda $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(NVCC_CFLAGS) --output-file $@ $<

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that it worked when I did the following.

nvcc *flags* -Xcompiler -fopenmp -fgomp *file stuffs*

Thanks to Tudor

Comment: It says I have to wait two days.